# Using HTML forms to submit info to sql database

Tags: html, sql, forms, plsql

I created a html form on Toad for oracle, and I am trying to make a form where the user inputs their ID and Employee Name and once submitted it will add that information to the data base.  I am mainly using PL/SQL to make procedures in which the first procedure presents the form and the second one submits and adds the information to the sql data base. My question here is how should i approach the second procedure in which it adds the information from the first procedure to the database.
My table in the database is called alfred_form_table and the columns are as follows: EMPID Integer and EmployeeName varchar2(25)
Here is my code:

```
procedure ALFRED_INSERT

IS

BEGIN

htp.p ('

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
</head>
```

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Create New User</h1>
</div>
<div id="section">
  <p width = 100% align="left">

');

 htp.p ('
 <form action="userINPUT" method="POST" NAME="INPUTFORM" >
      ');

  htp.p ('
  <table border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" summary="">

  <!--  Table -->
  <tr> Register New User </tr>

    <tr> <td>Employee ID: </td>
         <td><input type="text" name="EmployeeID" value=""/></td></tr>

    <tr> <td>Employee Name: </td>
         <td><input type="text" name="EmployeeName" value=""/></td></tr>
     ');

HTP.p ('

</html>

    </tr>
   </table>
   <br> </br>
      <input type ="submit" value="Submit Information"/>

  </form>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"> Alfred Inc. </div>

 </body>

   <!--  Check Form </!-->
  ');

 end alfred_insert;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example helps to better understand how to use htp with a form. Please also note that your html code is syntactically quite broken (just look at the `</html>` tag) and there is no obvious reason to use multiple htp.p statements.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE formPage
IS
BEGIN
    htp.prn('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>simple form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="formProcess">
<table>
<tr><td>First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>');
END formPage;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE formProcess(firstname IN VARCHAR2, lastname IN VARCHAR2, sex IN VARCHAR2, vehicle IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    htp.prn('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>simple form</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>First name:</td><td>'||firstname||'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name:</td><td>'||lastname||'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sex:</td><td>'||sex||'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Vehicle:</td><td>'||vehicle||'</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>');
END formProcess;
/
```